# Error concatenating directory path in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mkdir

I have over-complicated this problem with if/then scripts and super simple one line commands but for some reason I keep getting stumped.

I am trying to create a new directory `a-e` and place the files `a,b,c,d,e` inside of it. For some reason it will create the directory just fine but places the files inside of the `ps` directory instead of the new directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
mkdir /home/adminuser/ps/a-e && touch /home/adminuser/ps/a-e {a..e}
```

Comment: You've tagged this as being wanted for *Ubuntu Touch*, ie. a phone or tablet device using the PHONE OS now called Lomiri (*previously called Ubuntu Touch*).  If you want people to see or refer to the link you provided in your title; it needs to be in your actual question text (*any click on the title will only open this page! and some devices/setups won't show the title when you view this page anyway; thus all details need to be in your actual question text*)

Comment: `touch /home/adminuser/ps/a-e {a..e}` will do two things: 1) Update the modification/access/change time of the already existing directory `/home/adminuser/ps/a-e` and 2) create five files `a, b, c, d and e` in your current working directory ...  `ps` happened to be your current working directory and that is why ... `touch` takes arguments separated by spaces and therefore your passed arguments are actually 6 and not 5 as you expected.

Comment: you just want a `/` instead of a space there: `touch /home/adminuser/ps/a-e/{a..e} `

Answer (score 3):

Looks like maybe the last forward slash is missing to connect the path of the a-e directory and the filenames to be created?

Try `touch /home/adminuser/ps/a-e/{a..e}` and see if that works?